# how to specify the task of a submit type input?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UnAssign()
{
     ViewBag.Message = courseManager.Updated();
     return View();
}
```

In View:

```
    <form  method="post">        
        <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="UnAssign Courses" />
    </form>
    @section scripts
    {
        <script>
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function(event) {

                event.preventDefault(); 

            });
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function(event) {

                var confirmationmessage = "Are you sure you want to delete this?";

                if (! confirm(confirmationmessage)) {


                    event.preventDefault();

                } else {



                }
            });
        </script>
    }
```

By this Code I want to update one of my database column value to 0. in Update method i have already created an query along with made a connection with database. but in view when i press submit it doesn't do anything.want to know how can i call a specific action method and do this task without passing any model or value passing from the view?

Comment: You can use Ajax post.

Comment: The `action` attribute of the `<form>` determines which controller action you will hit. You have disabled the normal form submission with `event.preventDefault()` therefore your code won't do anything when you press the button.

Comment: Changed that part.. but still my submission is not going to my action. i tried  form action calling but its not doing anything.

Comment: Edit your question to show your changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two `.click` handlers

```
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var confirmationmessage = "Are you sure you want to delete this?";

            if (! confirm(confirmationmessage)) {

                //You do not need these here. Get rid of it
                //event.preventDefault();

            } else {

                 //here submit your form
                 $('form').first().submit();

            }
        });
```

To clean up your code a bit you could just use one `if` statement and remove the negation character.

```
 if (confirm(confirmationmessage)) {

                $('form').first().submit();

            }
    //jquery code does nothing after this. You already used event.preventDefault(); so the form will not be submitted
```

I would also advise you to look up how to use `Html.BeginForm` and `Ajax.BeginForm` since you are using MVC, might as well use the MVC stack.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/working-with-html-beginform-and-ajax-beginform-in-mvc-3/